# Побайтовый вывод

Tags: c++

Подскажите, что делает этот кусок программы. Не понимаю, как связаны char и value. Ведь по идее value только инициализируется. Не могу понять логику union.

```
union {
unsigned char bytes[8];
double value;
};
int i;
value = 859345.324;

// побайтовый вывод значение типа double
for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
    cout << (int) bytes[i] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

union дает вам разное представление одного и того же куска памяти. В примере вы сначала записываете в эту "общую" память число (double занимает тоже 8 байт), а потом читаете от туда как из байтового массива.